# Conditionally handle ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, loading

I have a full screen loading animation whenever Ajax start (most of them are action by the user) and hide on completion. At the same time I also have Ajax call to check server status using `setInterval`.

How do I separate the Ajax call to check server status because it is annoying if it appear as full screen. A small loading icon beside the status is fine.

May refer to the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $.LoadingOverlay("show");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(ajaxCall, 3000);

  function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'action': 'checkstatus'
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('online');
        $('.serverStatus').removeClass('ssOffline');
        $('.serverStatus').addClass('ssOnline').text('Online');
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log('offline');
        $('.serverStatus').removeClass('ssOnline');
        $('.serverStatus').addClass('ssOffline').text('Offline');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.ssOffline {
  color: red;
}

.ssOnline {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@1.5.4/src/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>

<p>Server status: <label class="serverStatus">-</label></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**global**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which is default `true`.This option can be use control global handlers like ajaxStart and ajaxStop.This will prevent the full screen loading icon from appearance.

If you want to show any other icon specific to this call you can use `beforeSend` handler

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function(event) {
  console.log(event)
  $.LoadingOverlay("show");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(ajaxCall, 3000);

  function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'action': 'checkstatus'
      },
      dataType: "json",
      global: false,  // changed here
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('online');
        $('.serverStatus').removeClass('ssOffline');
        $('.serverStatus').addClass('ssOnline').text('Online');
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log('offline');
        $('.serverStatus').removeClass('ssOnline');
        $('.serverStatus').addClass('ssOffline').text('Offline');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.ssOffline {
  color: red;
}

.ssOnline {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@1.5.4/src/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<p>Server status: <label class="serverStatus">-</label></p>
```

Comment: Hi, can you include the small loading icon beside the status for me too? Thank you.

Comment: @4LeaveCover Please do not post coding assignments. Not even if they look like a comment. That's rude. There are countless examples on this site alone of loading icons with jQuery Ajax. Do some research and pick one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property at `jQuery.ajax()` settings object, substitute using `beforeSend` at `$.ajaxSetup()` for `.ajaxStart()`, check if the current settings have the property set

```js
function log(message) {
  $("pre").text(function(_, text) {
    return text + message + "\n"
  })
}
// does not provide `settings` or `jqxhr` as argument
// we do not perform logic evaluation of current `$.ajax()` call here
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  log("ajax start");
});

$(document)
  .ajaxComplete(function(e, jqxhr, settings) {
    if (!settings.pollRequest) {
      log("not poll request complete\n");
      // $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    } else {
      log("poll request complete\n");
    }
  });

$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) {
    if (settings.pollRequest) {
      log("poll request beforeSend");
      // $.LoadingOverlay("show");
    } else {
      log("not poll request beforeSend");
    }
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(ajaxCall, 3000);

  function ajaxCall() {
    "ajaxCall";
    $.ajax({
      url: "data:text/plain,",
      pollRequest: true
    });
  }

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax("data:text/plain,")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>
click
</button>

<pre></pre>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5hfty5mc/